# How to make an IF statement and choose between 2 options Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Im trying to automate Login for a website. Sometimes when i enter the serialnumber of the product and it have been used before it will tell me this serialnumber has been used before, press continue to proceed, this will refer to another button/field/xpath.

This is my problem. When this occurs i want it to press continue. If the serialnumber HAVENT been used before it will click another button/field/xpath. So the program wont crash.

To summarize it, i want python/selenium to choose one of them if one of them is present.

How can i controll this? im new to this and trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.find_elements` method. In case of match, the element exists, it will return a non-empty list of found elements that is interpreted by Python as a Boolean `True`, otherwise it will return an empty list => Boolean `False`.
So your code can look like the following:

```py
first_el = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'first_element_selector')
second_el = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'second_element_selector')
if first_el:
    first_el[0].click() #or whatever
elif second_el:
    second_el[0].click()
else:
    print("None of elements found)
```